# Windows 7 'All Programs' folders self-close on right-click

Tags: windows-7, context-menu, start-menu

Odd issue on my Windows 7 Professional (32-bit) system.

If I click on the Start 'orb' then navigate to 'All Programs', then navigate to any of the folders that appear at the bottom of the list (like Accessories) and left-click, the folder contents expand with no issue. If I right-click, the context menu appears for half-a-second or so, then the popup goes away and the entire start menu dismisses.

I'm not sure how to debug this issue - I'm considering using Autoruns to try and disable things hooked into the shell one-by-one. Is there a way to use a tool like Process Explorer to narrow down the process that's actually dismissing the menus?

Comment: The best way to solve a problem like this is eliminate the possible causes by trial and error.

Comment: It sounds like your `Escape` key is/was stuck or firing on its own for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution (working temporarily at least:)

- Bring up Start Menu
- Right-click on All Programs -> Open All Users
- Delete desktop.ini