# Windows explorer folder context menu closes itself

Tags: windows-explorer, context-menu, shell-extensions, windows-8-desktop

Environment: Windows 8.0 Professional x64

When I call up the context menu on a selected folder in the listview (actual view mode doesn't matter, I reproduce for list, icons, and details), either via right-click or the context-menu button on my keyboard, the menu appears and then vanishes a second later.

It doesn't happen for all folders.  It doesn't happen for drives.  It doesn't happen in the folder tree pane.

If it happens for a folder inside a Documents library, it happens for both paths rooted at Libraries and filesystem paths.

The effect is similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/486416/29943) but I am in a different environment and it's happening to different folders.

I presume that a shell extension is causing an error/exception during context menu processing, and Explorer responds by destroying the menu.  Are such errors logged anywhere?  How can I discover what extension is failing?

The laptop where I'm observing this does suffer from Task Manager sporadically closing itself on launch, and also instability caused by overheating, but this problem is 100% reproducible so I don't think it is heat-related.

Comment: Sounds like the `Escape` key is stuck. What happens if you select a file and press `Ctrl+X`? Does its icon turn faded and stay like that? What happens if you press `Win`? Does the Start menu open and stay open?

Comment: @Syntech: I don't think a stuck escape key would cause symptoms that it only occurs on folders, not file context menus or drive context menus, and it also doesn't occur in the folder tree, only in the listview.  BTW Windows 8 doesn't have a Start Menu.

Comment: I was looking at the other question you linked to, but the question stands; what happens when you cut a file? Does its icon remain faded for more than a few seconds? It might indeed be an extension.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the reason was **Google Drive Backup & Sync** was running. As soon as I stopped it, my context menu was not disappearing anymore.

Comment: That is a program I have installed (well, it wasn't Backup and Sync back when I posted the question, just Google Drive, but it's basically just 2 versions of the same program) so it easily could be the troublemaker.  Thanks for narrowing that down.

Comment: Thanks!!!
This also fixed the problem I had with the auto-closing context menu (on any folder or file).

Answer (score 2):

> It doesn't happen for all folders. It doesn't happen for drives. It doesn't happen in the folder tree pane.

Is there anything different between the folders it happens with and the ones it doesn’t (e.g., do some contain media files or `desktop.ini` or have different attributes set or something)?

> I presume that a shell extension is causing an error/exception during context menu processing, and Explorer responds by destroying the menu.

If you can definitively rule out the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key and narrow down the problem to just the context-menu of folders, then it is indeed likely one of the folder-only shell-extensions. Like you surmised, what’s probably happening is that something you installed recently added a context-menu to folders, but the context-menu handler is poorly written and has a bug, so whenever it triggers, it is causing a problem, probably while trying to create a submenu or use an icon. (You’re lucky that all it’s doing is closing the menu and not outright crashing Explorer.)

> Are such errors logged anywhere?

It don’t believe that there is specifically a shell-extension-failure logging function, but you can check the Event Log (*Run* ⇨ `eventvwr`). If there’s anything, it will probably be under the *Windows Logs ⇨ Applications* branch, possibly with a source of `Application Popup` or `Application Error`.

> How can I discover what extension is failing?

You can use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to determine which extension is the culprit.

1. Run ShellExView
2. Click the *File Extensions* column to sub-sort by hook
3. Click the *Type* column to sort by extension type
4. Scroll down to the entries that contain `Folder` or `Directory` in the *File Extensions* column (look carefully because they can be mixed in with a bunch of other hooks; you can check the entry’s *Properties* dialog to see the field in a navigable edit control)
5. Disable one (right-click ⇨ *Disable* or select, <kbd>F7</kbd>)
6. You may need to [restart Explorer](http://www.howtogeek.com/77856/restart-the-windows-explorer-process-in-windows-8/).

Test to see if it still happens. If so, repeat for the next one. You can also disable multiple/all items by holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, but then you would have to re-enable them one-by-one to determine which one was causing the problem, so you may as well disable them one at a time.

---

[image: Screenshot of context-menu handlers in ShellExView]

Comment: I'd already tried disabling a bunch of extensions, and restarted explorer, and that didn't help.  I did notice that it seemed to only happen within subversion working copies.  I have TortoiseSVN installed, but that's a shell extension that I can't do without (it fact inability to reach its menus triggered this question) and it hasn't been installed or updated recently.  As I said, restarting all explorer.exe processes did nothing.  But the problem mysteriously went away after reboot.  My best guess now is that the TortoiseSVNCache.exe helper process was stuck in a bad state.

Comment: Ah, that narrows it down some, and that would have been my guess as well. Is it running? Have you tried simply killing `TSVNCache.exe`? (It restarts as soon as you right-click a folder.)

Comment: Well, TSVNCache obviously got killed by the reboot, and the problem hasn't come back.  If I ever see it again, cycling TSVNCache.exe will be my first step.

Comment: Just make sure to test the context-menu before and after as a diagnostic step to determine if it is indeed TSVN. `;-)`

Comment: report this to the TSVN developers so that they can investigate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can only figure out which extension it is, by trial & error.

Use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and disable 3rd part DLLs until you find the one which causes it.

Comment: It works after restarting Windows Explorer :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the folder which causes the trouble. Right click on it. Go to Properties and then go to customize and in it you will find a heading as " optimize this folder for", there select as " general items" and apply. This eliminates the problem and folders work fine without any limitation or drawback.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I'll definitely try that if the problem rears its ugly head again.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the issue on Win10 after i added a second Google Drive
The issue seems to be caused by "Backup and Sync from Google" in my case.  I stopped them and the problem was fixed.

1. Win task bar - "Show hidden icons" - select "backup and sync"
2. Settings (3 dots) - pick "Quit Backup and sync"

I restarted Backup and Sync and the issue seems to still be fixed.

1. Windows Start key
2. Backup and sync